# Combining RegEx's

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have two regex's that I am trying to combine. One is email specific and the other checks certain special characters. I have arrived at this solution following much toying:

```
"^([-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[\\w\\-ÀÈÌÒÙàèìòùÁÉÍÓÚÝáéíóúýÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûÃÑÕãñõÄËÏÖÜŸäëïöüŸçÇŒœßØøÅåÆæÞþÐð _]){0,80}$"
```

It does seem to check what I need it to, but for instance the following is still returned valid: `abc@foo` it does not force a full email address.

Am I using the correct approach or is there a simpler way to structure this RegEx? I'm on a learning curve with regex so all advice appreciated.

Comment: ... Why? Why must it be a single regex? Why not test one, then test the other? If you do them separately, you can provide *useful* error messages telling the user *exactly* what you didn't like about their input...

Comment: it's off a single input,so trying to infer an email address proved troublesome from a UI perspective

Comment: And do you really need to check for "certain special characters", or all letters that are not-ASCII?

Comment: Yep, I have inherited the second part of the regex so it's not open to change

Comment: `<input type="email" />` not good enough?

Comment: Its a search input, so not email specific unfortunately. It is required to be text

Answer (score 1):

Move the multiplier `{0,80}` inside the parenthesis:

```
"^([-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[\\w\\-ÀÈÌÒÙàèìòùÁÉÍÓÚÝáéíóúýÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûÃÑÕãñõÄËÏÖÜŸäëïöüŸçÇŒœßØøÅåÆæÞþÐð _]{0,80})$"
//                                                                                                                      here __^^^^^^^
```

Also `[a-zA-Z]{2,4}`  is really poor to validate TLDs, have a look at [IANA](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db).

And `me@localhost` is a valid email address.